# Scrape reviews from TA for a dendrogram

Tags: python-3.x

**Python 3**

I am trying to scrape reviews from tripadvisor for at least 20 different restaurants offering at least 4 different cuisines, i.e. Italian, Greek, American, and Chinese. Ultimately, I would like to create a dendrogram to see potential clustering within the results. So far I have the following, but I am not sure if it is possible to grab the reviews directly from the results page or whether I have to go into each restaurant pg:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g60763New_York_City_New_York.html"
response = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

restaurants = []
for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'ui_column is-9 shortSellDetails'}):
    for div in div.findAll('div', {'class': 'title'}):
        for a in div.findAll('a'):
            restaurants.append(a.text)
print(len(restaurants))
```

Comment: You will not get an answer to such a question (not that this is question in the first place in its present form!). Please [read how to ask questions on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @francium Thanks for the information, I've never posted before and didn't think about the 'question' I was asking for